# How to clear <input> and <textarea> fields as <type="text"> using a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, textarea

I've been developing a website for the past three weeks using HTML, CSS, and currently JavaScript for a school project. On the "Contact Us" page, I have a "form" (not defined as a form in code) where the user can leave their name, email address, phone number, and description. It looks like this:
[image]

The issue that I'm having is that when the user clicks the "Submit" button the four fields are supposed to clear the user's values and the placeholder text would reappear. So far, my code doesn't meet this requirement. The only thing that clears the four fields is when the user clicks the "Contact Us" link at the top right of the page. Currently, this is what I have:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Submit_Form()" />
```

```
function Submit_Form() {
  document.getElementById("Name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Email").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Phone-Number").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Text-Box").value = "";
}
```

Here is a more detailed example of my existing code: https://jsfiddle.net/Halomationdude14/pmhbxnjk/10/

I have tried a few different things to resolve this issue that I've learned so far such as:

1. Using the "onload" feature on the containing <div> that encases the form.
2. Using a <button></button> instead of input.
3. Using an event listener on the button (with an associated ID) instead of "onclick".

Aside from what I've read in my textbook, most of what I know about JavaScript has been learned from questions on this website. I have tried to format my code to how most people write theirs as seen throughout the Stack Overflow website but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: Replace `getElementByID` with `getElementById`and it should work then

Comment: I can't believe I messed up on the syntax like that, @Nesh. After changing the "D" to a "d", this worked for my code in JSFiddle, but it doesn't work when I run my HTML file directly. I'm using Firefox as my browser currently and haven't had issues like this in the past. Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: @Halomationdude any error in the console ?

Comment: @Nesh After correcting my typo, no, there aren't any errors in the console. This is why I'm confused as to why my code won't work when I run my .HTML file directly from my PC. Do I have my <script> in the wrong place? If I have empty functions in my .js file, would this cause problems? Does JSFiddle provide auto-correction? I've been using Notepad++ to create/edit my HTML, CSS, and JS docs.

Comment: @tacoshy I would remove this post if it was purely a typo issue to avoid embarrassment, but, unfortunately, there is something else going on here. As you can see, I've already corrected my typo in this post. I still have no idea why running my HTML file won't work but JSFiddle will.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what fixed my problem, but when I execute my .HTML file for the "Contact Us" website page, I am able to 'submit' my form now. I'm assuming that the problem was that my browser saw that I had empty functions in my .js file which was causing it to not respond when I clicked the "submit" button. I didn't have anything pointing to or using those empty functions, but now that I've filled them in and am using them, my form works perfectly.

Thank you to @Nesh for pointing out my obvious blunder as nicely as possible. I'd probably still be scratching my head if it wasn't for you! Just had to change the d in "Id" from a "D" to a "d".

```
function Clear_Fields() {
    document.getElementById("Name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Phone-Number").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Text-Box").value = "";
}
```

Here's the current state of my webpage: https://jsfiddle.net/Halomationdude14/pmhbxnjk/56/